# calculate the kernel of a germ map

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, singularity-theory, jet-bundles

I have a question, more about how to calculate the kernel of a certain map:

Let  the ring $\varepsilon_n=\lbrace f\colon (\mathbb{R}^{n},0)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}: f \quad\textit{is map germ}\rbrace$ and maximal ideal $\mathcal{M}_{n}=\lbrace f\in\varepsilon_{n}:[f]_{0}=0\rbrace$, and I have also shown that

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{M}_{n}&=\langle x_1,\ldots x_n\rangle\\
\mathcal{M}_{n}^{k}&=\langle x_{1}^{i_1},\ldots,x_{n}^{i_n}:i_1+\cdots +i_{n}=k\rangle 
\end{align*}

in the same way let's define $\overset{\sim}{\varepsilon_{n}}$ as the set of taylor's series
\begin{equation*}
    \overset{\sim}{f}=f(0)=f(0)+\frac{1}{1!}\sum\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(0)x_{i}+\frac{1}{2!}\sum\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{i}\partial x_{j}}(0)x_{i}x_{j}+\cdots
\end{equation*}
Let
\begin{align*}
 J\colon\varepsilon_n &\longrightarrow \overset{\sim}{\varepsilon_n}\\
        \hspace{4.1mm} f&\longmapsto \overset{\sim}{f}
\end{align*}
[image]
where $(2.4)$ is

[image]

which is what I indicated at the beginning, this is an excerpt from the book **Singularity points of smooth mapping-Gibson**

I don't know if it is very trivial, but I am a bit confused, I must show that the $$ker(J)=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{M}_{n}^{k}$$
any questions or solutions are welcome.

Comment: What's $[f]_0$?

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: $[f]_0$ is a representative of germ and from what I put of $\mathcal{M}_{n}^{k}$ is 
is finitely generated by monomial functions $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ y 
and I suppose that's why the intersection thing but i'm not sure

Comment: I guess $[f]$ is the representative and $[f]_0$ is the evaluation? Anyway, I am confused about your definition of $k$-jet. It is independent of $k$?

Comment: maybe it causes a bit of confusion, but being clearer $\mathcal{M}_{n}$ is the ideal of smooth maps that vanished at the origin, $k-jet$ space, simply a mapping is assigned its taylor polynomial up to degree $k$.

Comment: You've made an edit, so I assume that you now want $$ ker(J)=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{M}_{n}^{k}$$ rather than $ker(J^{k})=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{M}_{n}^{k}$ as the question currently shows.

Comment: Say $n=1$ if only for typing. If I am understanding, I think one direction is clear  e.g., $f(0)= x^2g(x)$ then $f(0)= f'(0)=0$ etc.... So to be shown is that if $f\in ker (J)$, i.e., $0= f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)= \cdots $ then, for each $k$, you can write $f\in \cal M^k$. For that, use the integral remainder form of Taylor's formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_remainder_of_multivariate_Taylor_polynomials.

Comment: You might also be interested in surjectivity: see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Borel%27s+theorem#:~:text=Borel's%20Theorem%20(also%20called%20Borel's,these%20as%20its%20actual%20derivatives.